# What Theorems can I use to solve a problem of this type?

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations

Find All 17 real solutions $(w,x,y,z)$ to the following system of equalities:
$$
2w+w^2x=x
$$
$$
2x+x^2y=y
$$
$$
2y+y^2z=z
$$
$$
-2z+z^2w=w
$$

I was thinking of using something related to cyclic sums, but I couldn't figure it out since one of the signs is negative, so I get 
$$
\sum_{cyc} (x+x^2y)=4z
$$
so finding the zeroes is no longer an easy process.

I also tried to find upper and lower bounds for the cyclic sum in the left hand side, using the AM-GM inequality but that really didn't help.

So I don't really know what to do, other than solving for each variable and substituting to end up with a monstrous polynomial, which makes me think there is an easier method I'm overlooking

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$x=\frac{2w}{1-w^2}$$
etc. Let's not worry about denominators being zero right now. This suggests setting $x_1=\arctan x$ etc. 
Then $x_1=2w_1$ or $x=2w_1\pm\pi$, so let's say
$x_1\equiv 2w_1\pmod\pi$. One then gets $z_1\equiv8w_1\pmod\pi$.

The last equation is
$$w=-\frac{2z}{1-z^2}$$
so $w_1\equiv-2z_1\equiv-16w_1\pmod\pi$. Therefore $w_1=k\pi/17$
where $k\in\Bbb Z$ so we have
$$(w,x,y,z)=\left(\tan\frac{k\pi}{17},\tan\frac{2k\pi}{17},
\tan\frac{4k\pi}{17},\tan\frac{8k\pi}{17}\right).$$

I suppose one ought to check there are no solutions with any variable
equal to $\pm1$.

Comment: This is a really elegant solution, I can see the right hand side resembling the double angle formula for tangent; what if I had a slightly different but similar problem it seems I won't be able to use such an identity. 
Is there any approach through algebraic principles?
I tried something similar to this
https://brilliant.org/practice/amc-am-gm-inequality/?p=8
but I only got the trivial solution from it

Comment: @Mahoma But surely this problem was **designed** to be solved with this method?

Answer (score 1):

All solutions are given by computing a resultant. We have the trivial solution $(x,y,z,w)=(0,0,0,0)$ and $16$ solutions parametrized by the $16$ solutions of $w$, which are the roots of the resultant polynomial
$$
f(w)=w^{16} - 136w^{14} + 2380w^{12} - 12376w^{10} + 24310w^8 - 19448w^6 + 6188w^4 - 680w^2 + 17.
$$
Note that all solutions are real. The there are exactly $17$ complex solutions, which are all real.

Comment: That looks like the monstrous polynomial I mentioned. After a few steps on that direction I gave up on it. Do you have a quick method to obtain the polynomial? (other than mix up the equations until we have only one variable)
At this point though, the only options I see are synthetic division, which does not look pleasant; or get a new system of equations in the roots using Newton Sums or Vieta's... maybe since quite a few of the terms are zero this could yield something "fast"

Comment: Oh, this is not "monstrous" at all, when dealing with systems of polynomial equations. For a reference, see Bernd Sturmfeld's book [Solving Systems of Polynomial Equations](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/cbms.pdf).

Comment: @Mahoma Just set $-w=f(f(f(f(w))))$ where $f(u)=2u/(1-u^2)$. Expanding and simplifying will give Dietreich's formula. Of course there is a nice formula for the iterates of $f$, coming from the fact that $f$ is the duplication formula for the tangent function.